# Radio buttons on previous fragment stop working after error E/TextView﹕ Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text

Tags: android, android-studio

> E/TextView﹕ Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text

is the message I get.
When I read on S.O. that using hardcoded values for colours like #ffffffff causes this so i used  values in my strings.xml but i still kept getting the same error.

My app is using multiple fragments in swipe view

Do text Views cause this? But none of my textViews are editable.

I also lose all the data on my previous fragments the moment this error pops in my logcat.
This include selected radio buttons mainly.
Apparently even their listener stops working.

here is my code:

```
package com.iiitk.zeda.aapkaauto;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Request extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener{

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    static LocationManager locationManager;

    static double[] gps=new double[2];
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    static TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher;
static View InforootView,PickuprootView,DestinationrootView,SchedulerootView,PoolingrootView,SummaryRootView;
    private static Context context;
    static ArrayAdapter adapter;
    static AutoCompleteTextView picker;
   static String st;
    static LocationManager mLocationManager;
   static  NumberPicker np3;
   static  NumberPicker np2;
    static NumberPicker np;
    static String longitude,latitude;
    static EditText specify,specify2;
    static Button GPS,GPS2;
       static  Spinner pickupspinner;
    static  Spinner destinationspinner;
    static String Src,Dest,Username,Contact,Email;
    static RadioGroup pickupgroup,destinationgroup,schedulergroup,payment;
    static LinearLayout scheduler,pool,nonpool;
    static RadioButton p1,p2,p3,d1,d2,d3,s1,s2,s3,prepaid,postpaid;
    static CheckBox Sharing;
    static TextView estimate,fare;

    public static String AreaList[]= {
            "22 Godam",
            "Airport",
            "Ajmeri Gate",
            "Birla Auditorium",
            "Birla Mandir",
            "Central Park",
            "Chauda Rasta",
            "City Palace",
            "Durga Pura",
            "EP",
            "Fortis Hospital",
            "Galaxy",
            "Gandhinagar Railway Station",
            "Gaurav Tower",
            "Hawa Mahal",
            "Hyper City",
            "Jagatpura",
            "Jaipur Railway Station",
            "Jantar Mantar",
            "Jawahar Circle",
            "Kanak Vrindavan",
            "Lalkothi",
            "Maharani College",
            "Narayan Singh Cicle",
            "Pink Square Mall",
            "Pt Education",
            "Raja Park",
            "Rajmandir",
            "Sanganer",
            "Sindhi camp",
            "SKIT College",
            "SMS Hospital",
            "SMS Stadium",
            "St Xaviers School",
            "T.I.M.E",
            "Tonk Phatak",
            "Transport Nagar",
            "WTP"};
    static Thread poolinglistener,pickuplistener,destinationlistener,schedulelistener,summarylistener;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
   public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_request);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Request.context=getApplicationContext();
        Runnable pickup=new pickuplistener();
         pickuplistener=new Thread(pickup);
        pickuplistener.setDaemon(true);
        pickuplistener.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Runnable destination=new destinationlistener();
         destinationlistener=new Thread(destination);
        destinationlistener.setDaemon(true);
        destinationlistener.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Runnable pooling=new poolinglistener();
        poolinglistener=new Thread(pooling);
        poolinglistener.setDaemon(true);
        poolinglistener.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Runnable schedule=new schedulelistener();
        schedulelistener=new Thread(schedule);
        schedulelistener.setDaemon(true);
        schedulelistener.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
       Runnable summary=new Summarize();
        summarylistener=new Thread(summary);
        summarylistener.setDaemon(true);
        summarylistener.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.request, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class selection implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener{


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                   long id) {
            if (view==pickupspinner){
                pickupspinner.setSelection(position);
                Src = (String) pickupspinner.getSelectedItem();
            }
            else{destinationspinner.setSelection(position);
                Dest = (String) destinationspinner.getSelectedItem();}



        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            pickupspinner.setSelection(0);
            destinationspinner.setSelection(0);
            Src = (String) pickupspinner.getSelectedItem();

            Dest=(String) destinationspinner.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch(position){
                case 0: return InformationFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 1: return PickupFragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 2: return DestinationFragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 3: return ScheduleFragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 4: return PoolingFragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 5: return SummaryFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 6: return PaymentFragment.newInstance(position+1);
                default:
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
               return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class InformationFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static InformationFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            InformationFragment fragment = new InformationFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public InformationFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             InforootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_info, container, false);



            return InforootView;
        }
    }
    public static class PickupFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PickupFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PickupFragment fragment = new PickupFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public PickupFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_pickup, container, false);
           GPS=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gps);

            GPS.setOnClickListener(this);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),R.layout.item_list);
           picker= (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

            picker.setAdapter(adapter);
            PickuprootView=rootView;
            EditText pickers=(EditText)picker;
            pickers.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // When No Password Entered

                }
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                    if (count%3 == 1) {
                        //we don't want to make an insanely large array, so we clear it each time
                        adapter.clear();

                        //create the task
                        st=s.toString();
                        GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                        //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                        task.execute(picker.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

            });


            if (pickuplistener.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)pickuplistener.start();



            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("Reached");
       Intent gpset;

            boolean statusOfGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(!statusOfGPS){
               gpset = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
               startActivity(gpset);

           }
            else {
               System.out.println("GPS is on");


                  new getGps();

try{
System.out.println(longitude);
               System.out.println(latitude);}
catch(NullPointerException e){}




           }
        }


    }



        public static class DestinationFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static DestinationFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            DestinationFragment fragment = new DestinationFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public DestinationFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_destination, container, false);
            DestinationrootView=rootView;

           if (destinationlistener.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)destinationlistener.start();


            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static ScheduleFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            ScheduleFragment fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public ScheduleFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_schedule, container, false);

            SchedulerootView=rootView;

            if (schedulelistener.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)schedulelistener.start();

            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class PoolingFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PoolingFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PoolingFragment fragment = new PoolingFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public PoolingFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_pooling, container, false);


            PoolingrootView=rootView;


                if(poolinglistener.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)poolinglistener.start();
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class SummaryFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static SummaryFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            SummaryFragment fragment = new SummaryFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public SummaryFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_summary, container, false);

                   SummaryRootView=rootView;


            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */

        public static PaymentFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PaymentFragment fragment = new PaymentFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        public PaymentFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (summarylistener.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)  summarylistener.start();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_payment, container, false);
            payment=(RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment);
            prepaid=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prepaid);
            postpaid=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prepaid);

            estimate=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.estimate);
            fare=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
            System.out.println("Reached");
            payment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (prepaid.isChecked()) {


                        estimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    } else if (postpaid.isChecked()){

                        estimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public static boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(providers)) {
                return false;
            }
            return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } else {
            final int locationMode;
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            switch (locationMode) {

                case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY:
                case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
                    return true;
                case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING:
                case Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
                default:

                    return false;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you pls post your code.

Comment: @Homosapiens Here I have edited..This is my main java file

Answer (score 0):

You need to store #ffffffff as a color not string. Create colors.xml like

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color>#ffffffff </color>
</resources>`

Comment: I have declared the colors as Drawables in strings.xml isn't that ok?

Comment: Besides, All the colors are appearing properly. Can you focus on my main problem?